# Stored procedure: how to use column as an input

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a simple stored procedure to count the number of empty records in my database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.cnt_empty 
    @col NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

        SELECT COUNT(@col) AS cnt
        FROM dbo.mytable
        WHERE @col = ''

END
GO

EXECUTE dbo.cnt_empty @col = N'field1' -- nvarchar(10)
```

I returns `0` for all the columsn I tested. What is wrong with this procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string is not being assessed as the column name, so you are actually running "where 'field1' = ''"

You need to do something like this

```
set @sql = 'select @cnt = COUNT(*) from [' + @tableSchema + '].[' + @tableName +
    '] where [' + @columnName + '] is not null';
-- print @sql; --uncomment for debugging
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@cnt bigint output', @cnt = @cnt output;
```

Look at http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/02/15/script-find-all-empty-columns-in-database/ for the full script.

Comment: But be careful! Using SQL like this has the potential to be a large SQL Injection security hole if you are taking this as user input: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

By doing this, your SQL statement is treating the parameter like a string, not like the name of a column. Take a look at [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). That will help you build up a SQL string and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

you are matching @col (i.e. 'field1')  against empty (i.e. '') in your where clause - that will never return a row.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is declare a variable like @sql VARCHAR(500)

Then do

SET @sql =  'SELECT COUNT('+@col+') AS cnt FROM dbo.mytable'

Then try use the built in sp  called sp_Executesql 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

This is because you are selecting the count of the variable not the count of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Basically using `EXEC` statement or `sp_executesql` should be your choice.